# Preventing add same data in one column (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm making an Java application that is able to modify MySQL database.
Because of specific kind of my application, I need to prevent from adding same data in column "username".

What I want to achieve is for example:

- adding "testuser" to table (Ok, that's easy)
- then adding "testuser" again, but I want my MySQL to ignore that INSERT command, or something like that.

Only solution I think about is doing this from level of my application:

- Trying to add "testuser" via proper method.
- Check if there is any "testuser" on my table
- If not -> add, if yes -> don't add

That solution may be OK, but I think it could be more elegant if I would prevent it from MySQL level, what do You think?

PS. If its necessary, I can delete my table and make new one, because there is not much data inside.

I would appreciate any support :)
Tom

Comment: try setting the UNIQUE attribute on username column http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp but you will have to manage exceptions

Comment: That exactly what I were looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution is given by Kondziutek:

> try setting the UNIQUE attribute on username column [w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) but you will have to manage exceptions

Thanks!